# How to make void update let audio play until end?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tore my hairs out on this.

How do I make this bit of code make the assigned audio file run completely? I know the update method runs only every frame, but how do I make it run until the audio is done? The audio starts then cuts immediately because it's every frame.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class checkifdone : MonoBehaviour
{

public AudioSource checkwin;
private bulbmanager bulbreq;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    bulbreq = FindObjectOfType<bulbmanager>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    checkaudio();
}

void checkaudio()
{
    if (bulbreq.bulbcount >= 8)
    {
        checkwin.Play();
    }
}

}
```

I tried putting it in void start() but that didn't help at all since start is for the beginning of the level.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Unity 3d and C# try using this function. 
it will play the audio file linked to checkwin in your inspector panel.

```
source.PlayOneShot(checkwin,vol);
// b is a bool
// this should stop either .play() or PlayOneShot() repeating or restarting
if(b){play audio function; b = false;}
```

Comment: This alone wouldn't help since it is still called every frame so you will have a lot of sounds playing parallel ;)

Comment: well i would assume one would be using it in an if statement to trigger it. :D
its suppose to play the audio once not overlap it continuously which checkwin.play() would.

Comment: Not exactly ;) `checkwin.Play()` starts the currently attached `AudioClip`. If it is running already it starts from the beginning again. `checkwin.PlayOneShot(audioClip);` (btw checkwin is an AudioSource and can not be parameter of PlayOneShot ;) ) replays the complete audioClip once. If it is called multiple times the clips are played parallel.

Comment: yeah that's why i mentioned use of an if statement...
-> if(b){play music; b = false}
that would completely stop either way from being played repetitively or restarted. :P

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, this script was on an empty object that had to check if bulbcount was 8, I moved the check to another gameobject and left the audio play function in the same place. I also used onEnabled for the gameobject that will play the sound, and in the start made it inactive.

So, when another gameobject (where the check of bulbcount is) knows the bulbcount is 8, it will enable the audio player, and (OnEnabled) it will play the sound.

Here's the script on the other gameobject (one that checks the bulbcount):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class LampScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bulbmanager bulbreq;
    public GameObject wincheck;
    //private bulbsmustcollect bulblvl;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bulbreq = FindObjectOfType<bulbmanager>();

        //bulblvl = FindObjectOfType<bulbsmustcollect>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (bulbreq.bulbcount >= 8)
        {
            wincheck.gameObject.SetActive(true);            

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (bulbreq.bulbcount >= 8)
            {
                //loop.Stop();
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 2");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code I put in the audio player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class checkifdone : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioSource checkwin;
    public GameObject wincheck;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        wincheck.gameObject.SetActive(false); //This is the same object where script is.


    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        checkwin.Play();

    }
}
```

Of course, let's not forget to assign everything needed. The audio now plays to full because it's independent of the update function of the other script file. Not sure if this is the best way but **it works!**

Answer (score 0):

From [AudioSource.Play](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html)

> If AudioSource.clip is set to the same clip that is playing then the clip will sound like it is re-started. AudioSource will assume any Play call will have a new audio clip to play.

So if you call `Play` every frame it allways starts from the beginning every frame.

---

You could simply add a `bool` flag for checking if it was already played instead of having multiple components and objects just for that. Or even easier: simply disable the component so `Update` isn't even called anymore

```
public class checkifdone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource checkwin;

    private bulbmanager bulbreq;

    // Flag to control of sound was already played
    private bool alreadyPlayed;

    private void Start()
    {
        bulbreq = FindObjectOfType<bulbmanager>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // If was already played do nothing
        if(alreadyPlayed) return;

        checkaudio();
    }

    private void checkaudio()
    {
        if (bulbreq.bulbcount < 8) return;

        // Set flag so Update is skipped in the future
        alreadyPlayed = true;

        // Or alternatively simply
        // disable this component:
        enabled = false;

        checkwin.Play();
    }
}
```